# Shipping address in Magento

Tags: magento

I have created a website in Magento.  When I place an order there are two options when inserting billing information.
"Ship to this address"
"Ship to different address"
There, the second method is selected by default. I want to select the first method by default.
Is there any method for this or do I have to make the adjustment in code.
Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the file `template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` you can force it with:

```
<?php $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setSameAsBilling(true) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no default methods for doing this.  You have to make an edit to the code to make this happen.  If you dig into the shipping method block and template files for the checkout process, you should be able to put in an override that will default to whatever option you select.